# Inject service in a simple class constructor with Angular2

Tags: class, typescript, angular

I created a Message class like this

```
import { ReflectiveInjector } from '@angular/core';

import { ApiService } from '../api.service';

export class Message {
        timestamp: number;
        message: any;
        api: ApiService;

        constructor(message: any) {
                let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([ApiService]);
                this.api = injector.get(ApiService);
                this.timestamp = message.timestamp;
                this.message = message.message;
        }
}
```

I'm not injecting *ApiService* directly in the constructor parameters because I'm trying to avoid this:
`let nm = new Message(message, this.api)`
I don't want the service to be in the parameters.

So I'm using the ReflectiveInjector but this code doesn't even work. I get this error : **EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): No provider for Http! (ApiService -> Http)** even if I include *HTTP_PROVIDERS* this way

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent, environment } from './app/';
import { appRouterProviders } from './app/app.routes';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
        appRouterProviders,
        HTTP_PROVIDERS,
])
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

How can I use the constructor to instantiate my class and inject my services like this :
`let nm = new Message(message);`

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

For some reason my answer was deleted without explanation, so here's the answer again:

This is exactly what I have been wondering; What if you really need to call a constructor in your code & still need to inject some things in your class? For example Angular2 tutorial's Hero class is anemic and does not contain any real-world functionality. That's not the case in my application, I need to have a domain objects that contain (a lot of) logic.

Anyway, this is my approach:

```
@Injectable()
export class MessageFactory {
  constructor(private service: Service)

  build(data: any): Message {
    let message = new Message(data);
    message.service = this.service;
    return message;
  }
}

export class Message {
  service: Service;

  constructor(private data: any) {
    // Can't call service here but it's okay for me...
  }

  doSomethingWithService(): {
    this.service.doSomething(this.data);
  }
}
```

So somewhere you can inject MessageFactory and create new instances of Messages:

```
export class MessageExampleComponent {
  constructor(private messageFactory: MessageFactory) {}

  makeMessageDoSomethingWithService(): {
    let message = this.messageFactory.build({just: 'an', example: 'here'})
    message.doSomethingWithService();
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if calling it MessageFactory is even a correct term, but I would like to have a feedback on this approach before some moderator just deletes this post without comment.

Answer (score 2):

you can use it while doing bootstrap like this

```
let nm = new Message(message);

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ 
  APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  [provide(Message,{useValue:nm})],
]).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

and for this

> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): No provider for Http!
>   (ApiService -> Http)

in service create constructor and import the **HTTP** like this

```
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
export class LoginService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {

  }
}
```

**for this purpose**

> Oh sorry, this is not how I want to use my class. For every message in
>   the chat I'm making, I instantiate a Message. I don't want just one
>   global Message class but several Message objects.

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ 
  APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  Message //you service here
]).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Oh sorry, this is not how I want to use my class. For every message in the chat I'm making, I instantiate a *Message*.  I don't want just one global Message class but several Message objects.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by using **@Inject**

```
import { Inject } from "@angular/core;
```

and i think it should work like this

```
@Inject(ApiService) api: ApiService;

import { Injectable , Inject } from "@angular/core;
    @Injectable()
    export class apiService {
        public constructor(@Inject(Http)  private http: Http) {}

    }
import { ReflectiveInjector, Component } from '@angular/core';

import { ApiService } from '../api.service';

@Component({
     providers: [ HomeService  ]
})

export class Message {
        timestamp: number;
        message: any;
        api: ApiService;

        constructor(message: any, @Inject(ApiService) api:ApiService) {                                      
                this.timestamp = message.timestamp;
                this.message = message.message;
        }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you !

Comment: My bad. It worked until I use this.api which is undefined. I'm not sure how to use the @Inject() decorator.

At the end, should I pass ApiService in the constructor like this:  
`new Message(message, this.api)` or ApiService will be injected without passing it in the constructor parameters ?

Comment: yes it should be in thhe constructor so when ever you use apiservice you can get http

Comment: My constructor looks like this

constructor(message: any, @Inject(ApiService) api) {
                this.api = api;
                this.timestamp = message.timestamp;
                this.message = message.message;
        }

I'm not really sure how to use @Inject() :/

Comment: if this is your message class then do this constructor(message: any, @Inject(ApiService) api:ApiService) { this.api = api; this.timestamp = message.timestamp; this.message = message.message; }

Comment: my bad you don't need to inject http in message you have injected it in apiService right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118467/discussion-between-jorawar-singh-and-greg).

Comment: I didn't need to use @Inject() in ApiService. I thought I could use my constructor like this : `new Message(message)` but I need to `new Message(message, this.api)`. Is there a way I can omit ApiService parameter ?

Comment: you can do this bu using injector like this 

public homeService = this.injector.get(HomeService);

public constructor(@Inject(Injector) private injector: Injector) {}


[Read more about DI](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html)